# Need help to switch to an iframe using cypress

Tags: cypress

I use Cypress to automate logging in to a web application, protected by an iFrame.

In my Selenium I can use a command to switch to iFrame:

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*@id='app']/iframe")));
After that I can access iFrame elements as well.

But with Cypress, I don't know the method to switch to frame?

Comment: The [cypress-iframe](https://gitlab.com/kgroat/cypress-iframe) gives you a lot of that capability, e.g switching to the iframe body element for tests within.

Answer (score 0):

Cypress doesn't give you an out of the box solution to work with iframes like Selenium or other tools. But thanks to the huge community, a lot of workarounds are available to work with iframes. One such way is:

1.Go to cypress/support/command.js and write:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getIframe', (iframe) => {
    return cy.get(iframe)
        .its('0.contentDocument.body')
        .should('be.visible')
        .then(cy.wrap);
})
```

2.In the tests write:

```
cy.getIframe('selector')
```

If you want to learn more about iframes and cypress, you can read this well written [blog post by Gleb Bahmutov](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/).

Comment: this solution is not working for me. Can you try to click on any item that comes up in the form when you open the url "http://staging.youvisit.com/tour/hanover?cif=1"